# Can I upgrade my Android if i have low resolution?

Tags: updates, 2.2-froyo, 3.0-honeycomb

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y Pro, which is a touch-and-type device, so the screen is small (2.6"), and I was wondering if i upgrade from my android 2.2 to android 3.0, will the display be as it should, or not? Many apps that are not designed to work with small screens will turn sideways, and i'm afraid that's going to happen if i upgrade my android.

Comment: How do you plan to upgrade?  Has the manufacturer released an update, or would you be installing a custom ROM?  If the latter, which one?  Note that Android 3.x was for tablets only, so if you upgrade past 2.3, you'd want to jump straight to 4.x.

Comment: @Wyzard i would install a custom rom, and if that's the case, i will install a 4.x version, but my ram is limited, i have 300MB of ram..

Comment: Jelly Bean needs about a gig of RAM (from my experience, and as a rule of thumb). Kitkat has been optimised better to support 512 RAM or more. If you only have around 300 RAM (290 I think) on the device, then it is going to be unusably slow. you are better off with the stock that came with it to be honest. The performance will be dreaful. I have a 786 ram device here with 4.1 on it and it is just HORRIBLE. I never use it. So the only one that MIGHT run is Kitkat, IF there is a ROM, but even that will be very slow. I'd say don't. 160 Mb internal memory will be an issue also.